# C# UWP api for internal message bus

Tags: c#, android, uwp, nsnotificationcenter, localbroadcastmanager

in a UWP c# application, how do I send a message from one object to another? This without creating specific parameters or methods.

I'm thinking of using a message bus, but I did not find anything for UWP C# app.

In iOS applications I used this https://gist.github.com/hollance/3121457
while in Android applications, I used the LocalBroadcastManager.

Is there any native or not API that allow me to do the same thing in an UWP application?

Answer (score 0):

Appservices should make that possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not what I need. I need an internal messaging mechanism between objects ... an internal message bus where you can send messages and read them